# Как корректно перезаписать файл на копьютере

Tags: файлы, javascript, html, json, php

Необходимые для web-сервиса данные хранятся на компьютере пользователя в формате JSON в текстовом файле. После загрузки и обработки в браузере нужно обновить файл с данными на компьютере. Отправляю запрос на сервер, который делает это примерно так

```
...
header ('Content-Type: application/json');
header ('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$_POST['fname'].'";');
echo stripslashes($_POST['fdata']);
exit();
```

В Chrome для существующего файла **xxxxx.yyy** сразу создается новый **xxxxx(1).yyy**, нет предложения перезаписать. Возможно, достаточно будет подсказки, как через настройки браузера заставить его спрашивать о возможности перезаписи файла.

В IE проблема в следующем, по ходу создается временный файл типа **xxxxx.yyy.???????.partial**, при попытке заменить его на **xxxxx.yyy** происходит ошибка, перезапись не происходит. Сервис одностраничный, между загрузкой файла и его сохранением на компьютер в обновлении страницы нет необходимости (если обновить страницу, то с перезаписью файла все ОК). Файл загружается при помощи ocupload-1.1.4.js, принудительный reset формы, задействованной в этом процессе после успешной загрузки файла эффекта не дает)

Comment: Ну почему же? Есть код (javascript), он загружает файл с компьютера (отправляет на сервер и через AJAX получает его содержимое) После внесения изменений отправляет через AJAX результат, сервер сохраняет результат на компьютер (кусок рабочего кода на php представлен). Все в общем случае работает. Проблема при попытке сохранить файл под тем же именем, т.е. перезаписать.
Есть подозрение, что проблема в том, что при загрузке файла браузер каким-то образом "блокирует" его от перезаписи через механизм <input type="file" ...>
Сам файл в этот момент доступен для перезаписи средствами ОС.

Comment: **От модератора** не вижу криминала в посте - тревога лишняя.

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь для того-же самого [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). Обновляйте данные там, а выгрузку оставьте, но как пользователь её сохранит - уже его дело.

Answer (score 0):

Не только в Хроме, но и например в любом браузерe в Mac OS при автоматическом сохранении будет подставлен постфикс к имени файла, что бы не затереть пользовательские файлы. Нужно что бы браузер спросил пользователя куда и под каким именем сохранить файл. Тогда уже в ручном режиме вы его замените, иначе никак.

Могу только предположить, что если при отправке файла на сервер сохранять его временно на сервере, делать редирект на другой URI (скрипт), где уже отдавать этот файл, может таким образом блокировка файла в вашем случае и отключится.